# Problemas al intentar instalar la dependencia de prisma con NPM

Tags: nodejs, npm

Estoy intentando configurar un proyecto, y a la hora de instalar la dependencia de prisma con el comando `npm i -D prisma` obtengo el siguiente error

```
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! prisma@4.8.1 preinstall: `node scripts/preinstall-entry.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the prisma@4.8.1 preinstall script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

Revisando los logs veo la siguiente captura
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por lo que sea, al intentar ejecutar el script `prisma@4.8.1 preinstall: node scripts/preinstall-entry.js` obtengo esos errores por terminal y la instalación se interrumpe.

Revisando e informándome leo de chekear la versión de node, pero piden una versión de 12 o superior y yo tengo la versión 14.16.0, por otro lado, npm completamente actualizado, ¿qué podría estar pasando? ¿problemas de path?
También he probado a eliminar la carpeta node_modules, y volver a ejecutar npm install con todo lo que hay en mi package.json, pero el error persiste...
Si se os ocurre algo lo agradecería

Un saludo!

Comment: que extraño, yo instalo la dependencia y no tengo errores

Comment: @infinit3Loop__ me estoy fijando que en mi carpeta node_modules, no tengo la carpeta scripts por ningún lado, y esta incluye el archivo preinstall-entry.js... alguna forma de corregir esto? estoy parado en este punto jumm.

Comment: te sirve alguna de estas respuestas? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57605441/error-this-is-probably-not-a-problem-with-npm-there-is-likely-additional-loggi

Comment: Nada, volví a borrar node_modules, package-lock.json y limpiar el caché con npm cache clear --force, y volver a instalar todo con npm install, y el error persiste. Aquí hay alguien con un problema parecido pero no consigo sacar nada en claro https://github.com/umami-software/umami/issues/1010
No sé si es buena idea actualizar mi versión de node, ya que podría darme errores de compatibilidades con otros proyectos que tengo y cargármelos.